# ansible match exact string from register result

Tags: ansible

I have below ansible tasks which compares list of packages against register output obtained from yum module.

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    pkgs: [ 'git', 'rsync', 'python36' ]
  tasks:
    - name: stats for installed pkgs
      yum:
        state: installed
      register: installed

    - name: Compare against register
      set_fact:
        unwanted_pkgs: >-
          [
           {% for value in installed.results %} 
              {% for pkg in pkgs %}
                 {% if value.name | regex_search(pkg) %}
                    " {{ value.name }}",
                 {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
           {% endfor %}
          ]

   - name: print 
     debug:
       msg: "{{ unwanted_pkgs }}"
```

Upon executing above playbook, debug task print output as :

```
git
git-core
git-core-doc
python36
python36-devel
```

While executing the task it prints additional packages (eg: git-core, git-core-doc and python36-devel which I have not defined in pkgs variable). How this can be avoided ?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          {% for value in installed.results %}
          {% for pkg in pkgs %}
          {% if value.name == pkg %}
          {{ value.name }}
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    git
    python36
```

The same can be achieved by intersecting the lists

```yaml
unwanted_pkgs: "{{ installed.results|map(attribute='name')|intersect(pkgs) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  unwanted_pkgs:
  - git
  - python36
```

Comment: Yes,  Thanks i am able to get exact list now :)